# How to get the transformation between two body frames in PyDrake

Tags: python, transformation, robotics, drake, pose-estimation

I have two frames at different joint locations of IIWA arm, using
`f1 = plant.GetFrameByName("iiwa_link_0", kuka_model) f2 = plant.GetFrameByName("iiwa_link_2", kuka_model)`

I want to find the transformation between these two body frames(f1, f2).

Getting error when using f1.CalcPoseInBodyFrame() :

`TypeError: CalcPoseInBodyFrame(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported: 1. (self: pydrake.multibody.tree.Frame_[float], context: pydrake.systems.framework.Context_[float]) -> pydrake.math.RigidTransform_[float]`

What is the correct way to approach this problem?

Thanks,
Sarvesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be helpful if you post the actual code giving you the error.

Worst case, you can do this:

```
context = ... # assuming you have a context where things are posed.

f1 = plant.GetFrameByName("iiwa_link_0", kuka_model)
f2 = plant.GetFrameByName("iiwa_link_2", kuka_model)
X_F2F1 = f1.CalcPose(context, f2)
```

Comment: If the two frames are rigidly connected, is there a way to do this without using a context?

Comment: You still acquire frames f1 and f2 and then try this:

```py
X_BF1 = f1.GetFixedPoseInBodyFrame();
X_BF2 = f2.GetFixedPoseInBOdyFrame();
X_F2F1 = X_BF2.inverse() * X_BF1.
```
Although, this assumes they're rigidly connected to the same body. If it's a frame on one body for which there's a welded path to another frame on another body, that becomes trickier.